# Как зарегистрировать слушателя?

Tags: битрикс

Нужно добавить кнопку в форму изменения скидки. Порывшись в коде нашел обработчик `OnAdminContextMenuShow`. Как мне подписаться на него из своего модуля?
В документации нашел только один способ: прописать ручками в `/bitrix/php_interface/init.php` слушателя с помощью функции `AddEventHandler`. Как это автоматизировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы зарегистрировать событие в своем модуле используется `RegisterModuleDependences`
 пример : 
`RegisterModuleDependences(
  "iblock", // модуль в котором происходит событие
  "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate", // название события
  "mymodule", // название вашего модуля
  "cMainRPJ",// имя вашего класса обработчика
  "onBeforeElementUpdateHandler" // имя вашего метода обработчика
);`

Все это должно быть в методе при установке модуля `DoInstall`